Is there any way to get the Chat transcript from the messaging session object, I want to get the chat and display that chat with a associated case
I want get the transcript of chat from the messaging session object and display that same with the associated case page.
The chat is coming from a bot which is deployed on a experience site. I am able to see the chat on my MS conversation tab but how do i get that transcript.

I don't suppose you figured this out did you? I have precisely the same goal, and am having precisely the same problem.
